# Can't insert data in my database when using http post in REST API with Slim Framework version 2.4.2

Tags: php, rest, api, slim

I'm building a REST API with Slim Framework to manage some phone contact data, and I got a problem using the http post to insert data in my database. This one doesn't work, and I don't know why.

Here is my code :

```
 require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();


try {
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:data/GestionnaireContact.sqlite');
    $db->exec( 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;' );
} catch(PDOException $ex){
    die($ex->getMessage());
}    

$app = new Slim\Slim(array(
    'mode' => 'development'        
));

$app->contentType('application/json');

$app->post('/contacts',function() use ($app,$db) {
    $body=json_decode($app->request->getBody());
    $nom = $body->nom;
    $prenom=$body->prenom;
    $email=$body->email;
    $telephone=$body->telephone;


    $req = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO contact (nom, prenom, email, telephone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    try {

        $req->execute(array($nom, $prenom, $email, $telephone));
    } catch (\PDOException $ex) {
        die("Erreur ".$ex->getMessage());
    }

    returnResult('add', $req->rowCount() == 1, $db->lastInsertId());
});

function returnResult($action, $success = true, $id = 0)
    {
        echo json_encode([
            'action' => $action,
            'success' => $success,
            'id' => intval($id),
        ]);
        die();
    }
```

Everything seems correct to me. I tested with get request to retrieve data and it worked perfectly but with post, it doesn't work at all I got that error :

```
{"action":"add","success":false,"id":0}
```

, and I don't know why.

Comment: `$req->errorCode()` returns something?

Comment: Thx for the reply. I've already solved my issue. It was weird, I just restarted my PC, and everything works now.